# Spring JDBC insert into DB will not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

For some reason my jdbctemplate is not picking up the info in my application.properties file. I can only insert in my db when I make my own connection exposing my username and password in the file. Why isn't spring boot picking this up? Please help!

I am calling the addTaglocation mode while I am still reading tags from multiple RFID readers.  Would this cause the issue? If so how do I solve it.  Thanks in advance.

I start reading the tag from multiple rfid readers from a controller.

Full class where I am calling the create method (addTaglocation method):

```
public class TagInventory extends AlienClass1Reader implements 
    MessageListener, TagTableListener{

    private final int MAX_THREAD = 50;
    private Thread[] m_run_process = new Thread[MAX_THREAD];
   private AlienReader[] m_inventory = new AlienReader[MAX_THREAD];
   public boolean stopInventory = false;
     ReaderProfileService rps;
     VehicleService vs;
    private boolean ThreadStop = true;
    private int lastThreadId = -1;
      private MessageListenerService service;
    private TagTable tagTable = new TagTable();
     private TagTableListener tagTableListener;

     private static final Logger log =LogManager.getLogger(TagInventory.class);


     @Autowired 
     TaglocationDAOJdbc taglocationDAOJdbc;


    public TagInventory() throws AlienReaderException, IOException{
        Start();
    }

    public void stopTag() throws AlienReaderException{
        Stop();
    }

    private void Stop() throws AlienReaderException{
         ThreadStop = true;
         for (lastThreadId=0; lastThreadId < Reader.ipAddress.length; 
    lastThreadId++){
             if(m_inventory[lastThreadId] != null){
                 m_inventory[lastThreadId].stopInventory = true;
                 service.stopService();
                 try{
                     Thread.sleep(200);
                 }catch(Exception e){
                     e.getMessage();
                 }

                 //m_inventory[lastThreadId].close();

                 m_inventory[lastThreadId].open();
                 m_inventory[lastThreadId].autoModeReset();
                 m_inventory[lastThreadId].setAutoMode(AlienClass1Reader.OFF);
                 m_inventory[lastThreadId].setNotifyMode(AlienClass1Reader.OFF);
                 m_inventory[lastThreadId].close();


             }
         }

    }

    private void Start() throws AlienReaderException, IOException{
        ThreadStop = false;

         service= new MessageListenerService(3900);
         service.setMessageListener(this);
         service.startService();

          for (lastThreadId = 0; lastThreadId < Reader.ipAddress.length; lastThreadId++)
          {
              m_inventory[lastThreadId] = new AlienReader(Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId], Reader.port, Reader.username[lastThreadId], Reader.password[lastThreadId]);
              log.info("taginventory reader: "+ Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId]+"Thread: "+lastThreadId);
              m_run_process[lastThreadId] = new Thread(new StartInventoryThread(Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId], Reader.port, Reader.username[lastThreadId], Reader.password[lastThreadId], m_inventory[lastThreadId]));
              m_run_process[lastThreadId].start();
          }
          --lastThreadId;

          try
          {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              ex.getMessage();
          }


    }

    class StartInventoryThread implements Runnable{

        private String ip;
        private int port;
        private String user;
        private String pwd;
        private AlienReader ar;


        StartInventoryThread(String ip, int port, String user, String pwd, AlienReader ar){
            this.ip=ip;
            this.port=port;
            this.user=user;
            this.pwd=pwd;
            this.ar=ar;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(!stopInventory){
                    startRead(ip,port,user,pwd);
                }
            } catch (AlienReaderException | InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void tagAdded(Tag tag) {
        log.info("NEW TAG: " + tag.getTagID()+ " LAST SEEN DATE: "+ tag.getRenewTime());

    }

    @Override
    public void tagRemoved(Tag tag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void tagRenewed(Tag tag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void messageReceived(Message msg) {
         if(msg instanceof ErrorMessage){
            //   log.info("Notify error from " + msg.getReaderIPAddress());

         }else if (msg.getTagCount() == 0){

                    log.info("No tags!");
         }else{
            //log.info("Message received from: "+msg.getReaderIPAddress());
            Tag[] tagL=msg.getTagList();
            //String[] tagLString=new String[tagL.length];
            for (int i=0;i<msg.getTagCount(); i++){
                Tag tag = msg.getTag(i);
                //System.out.println("Tag ID: "+tag.getTagID()+ " Last Seen: "+tag.getRenewTime());
                this.tagTable.addTag(tag);
                // log.info("Tag ID: "+tag.getTagID()+ " Last Seen: "+tag.getRenewTime()+ " Receive Antenna: "+tag.getReceiveAntenna());

                //System.out.println("Tag: "+tag+ " Last Seen: "+tag.getRenewTime());
            }

          }
         //check readerprofile
          try {
            updateLocation(Reader.ipAddress[this.lastThreadId]);
             this.tagTable.removeOldTags();
        } catch (NoReaderInfoException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoVehicleException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void addTaglocation(Taglocation tl){
        Taglocation newtagloca= new Taglocation(tl.getReadername(),tl.getRfidtag(),tl.getZone(), tl.getTaggingsource(), tl.getVineight(), tl.getZonedate());


    taglocationDAOJdbc.addtaglocation(newtagloca);
        log.info("ADDED TAGG INFO!");           
    }

    public void updateLocation(String read) throws NoReaderInfoException, NoVehicleException{
        //update location of vehicle when tag read by readers
        log.info("IN UPDATE LOCATION with reader: "+read);
         Tag[] temp;

         temp=this.tagTable.getTagList();

         for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
             log.info("get taglist");
                Tag tag = temp[i];
                String rfid=tag.getTagID();
                Timestamp newDate=new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
                Taglocation tl=new Taglocation(read, rfid, read, "", "vineight", newDate);
                addTaglocation(tl);

         }


}


    public void startRead(String ip, int port, String user, String password) throws AlienReaderException, InterruptedException, UnknownHostException{
        String myIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("ip"+ ip);
        AlienReader ar= new AlienReader(ip, port, user, password);
        ar.open();
         log.info("Reader" + ar.getIPAddress());

        ar.setNotifyAddress(myIP, 3900);
        ar.setNotifyFormat(AlienClass1Reader.TEXT_FORMAT);
        ar.setNotifyTrigger("TrueFalse");
        ar.setNotifyMode(AlienClass1Reader.ON);

        ar.autoModeReset();
        ar.setAutoStopTimer(5000); // Read for 5 seconds
        ar.setAutoMode(AlienClass1Reader.ON);
        tagTable.setTagTableListener(tagTableListener);
        tagTable.setPersistTime(5000);

        //tagTable.setPersistTime(1800000);
        ar.close();

        long runTime = 10000; // milliseconds
         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         do {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         } while(service.isRunning()
         && (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) < runTime);

         // Reconnect to the reader and turn off AutoMode and TagStreamMode.
         log.info("\nResetting Reader");
        ar.open();
        ar.autoModeReset();
        ar.setNotifyMode(AlienClass1Reader.OFF);
        ar.close();

    }




}


(UPDATED)
```

Application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

(UPDATED)
taglocationJDBCTemplate file

```
@Repository
public class TaglocationJDBCTemplate implements TaglocationDAO {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public void create(Taglocation tl){
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator(){
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(final Connection connection) throws SQLException {
             PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TAGLOCATION (READERNAME, RFIDTAG, TAGGINGSOURCE, ZONE, VINEIGHT, ZONEDATE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                     Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.setString(1, tl.getReadername());
            ps.setString(2,tl.getRfidtag());
            ps.setString(3, tl.getTaggingsource());
            ps.setString(4, tl.getZone());
            ps.setString(5, tl.getVineight());
            ps.setTimestamp(6, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())); 
             return ps;
          }
    }, keyHolder);
    return (Integer) keyHolder.getKey();
}
```

controller file:

```
@RestController
public class TagInventoryController {

  @Autowired
  TagService tagService;


  @RequestMapping("/runTasks")
  public String tagRead(){
    tagService.startTagRead();
    return "Readers are activated.";
  }
}
```

Comment: So the context is working....it just won't insert the record and there is not error.....

Comment: OK....so its not inserting record because there was no id....I have the id auto incrementing...how do i get last id?  Do I search for it before I insert record?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot (according to your tags) then why are you creating a new context to retrieve the bean?! Never do that. Inject the dao instead of creating a new context. Also if you are really using Spring Boot you can completely remove your `SpringJDBConfig` as all of that is already done by Spring Boot.

Comment: OK changed that but it still is not inserting record. Updated create method.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, remove your configuration and add 3 properties to your `application.properties` to configure the `DataSource`, spring boot will do the rest. And put `@Transactional` on your service method. Trying to insert stuff in the database without a transaction isn’t going to work.

Comment: Added Transactional and still does not work....Added properties to application.properties file and deleted config file.

Comment: I am also running 3 other threads reading data in at the same time. Does that matter?  @M.Deinum

Comment: I can see that my my method to insert has been called but it just does not run the jdbctemplate.update or jdbctemplate.queryForObject....why?

Comment: There must be something you aren't showing here. As what you have shown here should simply work. So there must be something in your project that breaks this. However with only a snippet of the SQL/JDBC being used that is hard to pin point.

Comment: That is the complete taglocationJDBCTemplate file and application properties file. Added more code. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of `TaglocationJDBCTemplate`? That won't work as that would lead to `NullPointerException`s. As I stated you should inject the dependency NOT create a new one or create an application context because you need on.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Finally got it to work! Added a component and set it to the taginventorydao interface. Created a method in component to return the method that was in the interface. Created a "annotationconfigapplicationcontext" in addTaglocation method, go the context bean and called the method in the component. Then closed the context. WHEW!

Comment: You are still doing it wrong. You shouldn't create a context, that is the wrong way, you should inject the dao not create it because you need it. Creating the context is even worse (well unless you want to run into memory issues, weird transactional issues, running out of db connections etc. etc.).

Comment: Please give an example of what you are suggesting. Thanks.

Comment: Just create an `@Autowired` annotated field of type `TaglocationJDBCTemplate` in the class containing the `addTaglocation`. I'm assuming that that is a spring bean as well.

Comment: Still not working....added more code that may help find issue.

Comment: This does not work unless I create a context....why is that happening?

Comment: Your `TagInventory` isn't managed by Spring and as such won't auto wire etc. Let Spring manage it instead of you creating new instances of it.

Comment: You are correct...finally added it as a component.  Thanks!

Comment: One more question...so when I add the class as a component...it runs all the methods in that class all at once????

Comment: No. It tells Spring that it should manage the instances.

Comment: OK all of my database actions work fine. But now when I try to start my multiple readers to read them, I get an error creating bean exception. Its an java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception. Will post as different question.........